# Ckeditor, uploading an image

Tags: php, ckeditor

We keep getting a 500 internal server error when using Ckeditor to upload an image from local machine. [Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juc5i.png)

This is the error we have been getting: /ckeditor/filemanager/connec…hp/upload.php?Type=Image&CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en-gb 500 (Internal Server Error)

We have removed the .htaccess file and we're still getting this error.

So, we copied the whole folder to another hosting package. And when we tried to run the phpinfo file, it worked absolutely fine there.

But it is not working on our VPS server and is giving 404 Page not found: https://www.diarydirectory.com/redesign/assets/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/phpinfo.php

GoDaddy aren't being helpful at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions at all? Our team have exhausted all options

Comment: it prompts for username & password

Comment: have you checked your error log? Error log contains detail of 500 internal server errors.

Comment: @RamRaider yes, we have password protected the site as it's a development site. And you need a subscription to use the website.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I have attached an image with the details of the error.

Comment: I notice your screenshot has a double slash highlighted. Have you tried correcting that first?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes we have done that and it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @I.P, what you have added is just browser console error from the javascript of ckeditor. I am talking about PHP error log, which is on your server. You can find that on your GoDaddy cPanel.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla yeah we checked the error log and there is nothing related to Ckeditor. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok, Have you given a proper path to upload destination? If yes, please check folder has proper permissions.